# Repository pattern to execute a stored procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm trying to use repository pattern for my vsto project.

How do I use a repository pattern to execute a stored procedure? I'm using Entity Framework. Any link for code sample would really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link guided me. [[Link]](http://code-clarity.blogspot.com/2012/02/entity-framework-code-first-easy-way-to.html)

But when you execute stored procedure you have to put "exec" informant of SP name
Eg: if sp is "sp_aa"

string should be "exec sp_aa"

Answer (score 6):

To your generic repository add

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecWithStoreProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters);
}
```

And then you can call it with any unitofwork/repository like

```
IEnumerable<Products> products = 
             _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.ExecWithStoreProcedure(
             "spGetProducts @bigCategoryId",
             new SqlParameter("bigCategoryId", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = categoryId } 
      );
```

Comment: How do you add ProductRepository to _unitOfWork can you please add a sample code of _unitOfWork class how it implementa ProductRepository there?

Comment: Cannot find SqlQuery over Database ?

Answer (score 4):

A non generic solution in your repository would be:

```
private int ExecWithStoreProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
   return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC " +  query, parameters);
}
```

And then a few typical examples of use:

```
var param = new SqlParameter("SomethingToCheck", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = shortCode };            
var result = ExecWithStoreProcedure("mySchema.myStoredProc @SomethingToCheck", param);
```

with multiple parameters:

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter("SomeCode", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = shortCode };
var param2 = new SqlParameter("User", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = userName };
var result = ExecWithStoreProcedure("mySchema.myStoredProc @SomeCode, @User",  param1, param2 );
```